# how to pass query URL in wso2esb to endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm having the following API configured in WSO2ESB:

```
   <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="service" context="/service">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="https://webapps.localhost/service.php"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

The call works fine and POST content goes fine to the endpoint.

```
curl -X POST -d "a=1&b=2" localhost:8280/service
```

from the service.php file I can extract POST parameters fine.

Now if I want to have dynamic GET parameters passed as is to the endpoint, what would be the way to do it?

```
curl -X POST -d "a=1&b=2" localhost:8280/service?c=3&d=4
```

I know (at least what i understood) property mediator could be used but this is for known parameters in the query url (for example, $url:c) but I don't want to limit it, just pass the query url as is to the destination endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should work out of the box. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Unusual+Scenarios+for+HTTP+Methods+in+REST#UnusualScenariosforHTTPMethodsinREST-UsingPOSTwithQueryParameters

Answer (score 1):

You can access the resource path through REST_URL_POSTFIX

```
<property name="path" expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX"/>
```

According to your request URL, `$ctx:path` should contain `?c=3&d=4`

Answer (score 0):

Just to update here, use Address EndPoint instead of HTTP EndPoint (which is based on URI-Template)

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do is defining two variables on the endpoint's URI template, and then use the property mediators to set them.

Something like

```
<http method="POST" uri-template="https://webapps.localhost/service?c={uri.var.c}&d={uri.var.d}"
```

Then use the property mediator to set the property `uri.var.c` and `uri.var.d` with the intended values.